# when me run my project its give me like this "> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED"

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, error-handling

**I'm just creat a project with this cmd**
`npx react-native@latest init projectone`

**then direct run project with this cmd**
`npx react-native run-android`

but after this it will give me like this error msg

**error:**

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> 9 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 7 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-android-0.71.8-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.8) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download react-android-0.71.8-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.8)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.71.8/react-android-0.71.8-debug.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.71.8/react-android-0.71.8-debug.aar'.
> > No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
he.org)
he.org)

he.org)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\projectone\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)    at C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\projectone\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16       at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\projectone\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\projectone\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\projectone>

***how to solve this error please help me to solve this error***